# How do I specify the URL of your Facebook page in the href parameter of the button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have a like button on my website and I created it prior to having a fb fan page for my website. Now that I have a fanpage, I want to link my website with my fan page. How do I do that? It says:

> Simply specify the URL of your Facebook page in the `href` parameter of the button

- but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest starting from scratch since you cannot find your like button code.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/.  Configure the like button to your desires, and copy the code from there.